# Tables stored time as UTC how take into account day light savings

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

The tables are storing times as UTC but I need to convert the times in GMT taking into account day light savings. How can this be done in SQL so the query doesn't have to be amended when the time changes.

Comment: For most intents, UTC and GMT are interchangeable, given that GMT has a zero offset from UTC. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: For example the user selected 10.00 in the application but this is submitted to the database as 09.00 I need logic to take into account the time zones. Thanks

Comment: UTC and GMT are usually used [interchangeably](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=utc+gmt+difference). Please provide sample data.

Comment: I need to take into account day light saving

Comment: AFAIK [GMT Does not have day light saving rules...](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo)

Comment: And just as a heads up: dealing with local time and day light savings is [a recepie for insanaty.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 
           SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
                                MyTable.UtcColumn), 
                        DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) 
   AS ColumnInLocalTime FROM MyTable
```